# What is the fourier transform of $\operatorname{sinc}^4(kt)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have to use Parseval's Theorem. I used it and ended with the integral of $(\operatorname{sinc}^2(kt))^2$.
I know the Fourier Transform of $\operatorname{sinc}^2(kt)$ is the triangle function but I don't know how is the triangle function in frequency domain.

If someone can tell me how to solve this problem I will be grateful.

Comment: Can you use the fact that the FT of a product is a convolution, and hence the answer here is the triangle function convoluted with itself?

Comment: I don't think is enough with that. Right now I have the FT of sinc^2(kt) that is the triangle function. In other words the (triangle function)^2 but I don't know what "equation" to put in "triangle function" so I can evaluated the integral.

Comment: The usual definition of a triangle waveform/function is the following:
$$\Lambda(x)\equiv\begin{cases}
0 & \left|x\right|\geq1,\\
1-\left|x\right| & \left|x\right|<1.
\end{cases}$$

You can try to devide the problem into segments when doing your calculations, I mean, by looking at the convolution as a sliding of one triangle function onto another.

Comment: Still not get it. What do you mean with "at the convolution as a sliding of one triangle function onto another"?

Comment: I think it would help if you would write down what you have done? You ended $\mathrm{sinc}^4(kt)$, but where did you start?

Comment: https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoftaee261/PS-5-2007-Solutions.pdf
Refer this site for detailed solution